# Application insights configuring using application insights status monitor in windows server 2012?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am trying to configure the application insights for asp.net web application hosted in IIS server of windows server 2012 using application insights status monitor. For that I have logged into azure portal and select required application insights resource, then I clicked on **Add Application Insights** button in status monitor. At that time I got the error like below screenshot.

[image]

But I have all sdk dependencies installed in the following path:

[image]
Can you please tell me how to resolve the above error as soon as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting the issue! We did breaking change in the latest version and as a result it becomes broken when updated only partially or installed without following update. We're working on the fix:  https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Announcements/issues/16

For now you can finish the full update by clicking on Update is available link in the bottom left corner and Install SDK 2.4.0
[image]